# When to use $sanitize and $sce ? What's differences between them?

Tags: angularjs

I 'm trying to understand what's the difference between properties.

Please help with practical examples. When to use them?

Such questions are not found in this forum.
Help me please.

Answer (score 6):

`$sce` is the service that actually chooses whether or not a string is safe to use and whether or not it should be sanitized. If it's HTML it is run through `$sanitize` if it's available. You probably won't ever need to use `$sanitize` - since all strings are escaped by default, you just selectively trust HTML using the `$sce` service.

[You can read more about $sce here.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce)

Comment: If you build up DOM elements by hand, they are NOT escaped - you must do so or face the wrath of XSS.